# How to upvote/like a post in django

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner to django programming. I have been trying to add a like button to the post which is posted by the user.
In my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Please help in adding a like button to my blog.

Answer (score 2):

It's basic database structure, you can simply use a [many to many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) where you store every user that has liked/upvoted the post :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    upvoted = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. Can I know what should I add in views, urls and html